# Security Analysis Tool for MS Access 2010

Tags: security, ms-access-2010

I'm looking for a security analysis tool that will scan VBA code and determine if there are any security vulnerabilities. Is there such a tool? I've looked in to VBDepend but this doesn't seem to highlight security vulnerabilities. I've used Fortify for a C# application but I don't believe it works for MS Access.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool. If your code doesn't have API calls neither run external commands using, say, *Shell*, there are no *security vulnerabilities* except those that might be native to Access - and finding these is a superior task.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you please provide me some examples or methods to test it via shell?

Comment: `Shell` is in internal command of VBA. Just search for it in "All modules".